# A point is isolated iff the corresponding singleton-set is contained in *some* base

Tags: general-topology, analysis

If $(X, \tau)$ is a topological space, then a point is called isolated iff $\{\xi\} \in \tau$. Now a base $\mathcal B$ for a topological space is a collection subsets such that each open set could be written as a union of sets from $\mathcal B$.

Now does the following hold? A point is isolated if $\{ \xi \} \in \mathcal B$ for *some* base?

*Proof*: The sets of a base are open, hence if $\{\xi\}\in \mathcal B$ then $\xi$ is isolated. Conversely, if $\xi$ is isolated, then $\{\xi\}$ must be open, so if $\mathcal B$ is some base, then $\{\xi\}$ is a union of element from $\mathcal B$, but as it is a singleton we must have $\{\xi\}  \in \mathcal B$ (this even gives that $\{\xi\}$ must be contained in every base). $\square$

I am just asking because I am reading a paper were the authors compute the sets of isolated points for different topologies, and I have the feeling that some of their arguments could be simplified by the above observation (because then we simple need to consider one specific base, instead of every possible base), but maybe I have overlooked something?

So does the above hold?

Comment: What you’ve written is correct. The following are all equivalent: $\xi$ is isolated; $\{\xi\}$ belongs to some base for $\tau$; $\{\xi\}$ belongs to every base for $\tau$.

Comment: Okay, thank you! Maybe you want to write it as an answer so I can mark this as checked...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you’ve written is correct. The following are all equivalent:

- $\xi$ is isolated;
- $\{\xi\}$ belongs to some base for $\tau$; and
- $\{\xi\}$ belongs to every base for $\tau$.